# What is the opposite of "slowpoke"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

"**Slowpoke**" is informal and a rather disapproving term.

Do we have a noun that is the antonym of "**Slowpoke**" and is informal and a rather disapproving term?

The internet suggests "**speeder**", "**rusher**" or "**hurrier**" but non of these found in formal dictionaries.

Comment: Perhaps "speed**st**er" but that's not quite the right word. Putting it here in case nothing better comes along.

Answer (score 1):

The internet suggests many things, e.g. "go-getter", "go-ahead", but these may be slightly informal, I might suggest "hustler".

If "hustler" is a bit informal due to the slang, then maybe "busy-bee" or even "Workaholic"

Comment: At least in American English, "hustler" can have a completely different meaning and I would not use it in this way.

Comment: @swmcdonnell - In AmE *hustler* has several meanings, hard working, go getter being one them.  I once referred to an ESL speaker as a hustler, meaning they were an active, doer who produced results.  They, to my surprise, thought I had called them a sex worker.  I found myself quickly explaining and apologizing.  I think most native speakers will glean the correct meaning from context.  If there is a chance for misunderstanding, I would discourage its use.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about driving a car, some words that come to mind are:

- speed demon
- speedster
- Speedy Gonzalez (very informal)

"Slowpoke" is only very lightly disapproving, and these words carry a similar connotation.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the other suggestions are good, but can be just as negative as 'slow poke', as they suggest that a person has 'rushed' a task. Rushing something can produce inferior results. Many things require a person to take their time, but 'slow poke' of course suggests that they are dragging. So it depends if by "opposite" you mean a term that is positive.

There is the term "**an eager beaver**", which Webster's defines as "*a person who is extremely zealous about performing duties and volunteering for more*". It is not usually used in a negative sense, although some occasionally use it to mean that someone is *too* eager to begin something - perhaps rushing to begin, but not necessarily rushing the task itself.